# Opening a floating contextual menu by using GestureDetector onLongPress [ANDROID]

Tags: java, android, touch

I have a fragment implementing `onCreateContextMenu` (where the menu layout is inflated) and `onContextItemSelected` menu, and I set have set an `addOnItemTouchListener` on my RecyclerView to detect long-press. I created a `GestureDetector` instance in this listener and override the `onLongPress` method. I try to test whether the event is captured (by printing a toast message), and it works. However, when I'm trying to show the contextual menu when there is a long press by using this touch listener (my reasoning is because I want to intercept the listener so it the event won't propagate to the viewgroup's children), it doesn't show any contextual menu after longpress.
I have also applied `registerForContextMenu(recyclerView)`, also tried applying 
openContextMenu(recyclerView) but the compiler detects there is no method with such declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently I'm calling the openContextMenu from a fragment and the method's only available in Activity. So in the end I use getActivity().openContextMenu and it works.